# Missing Constraint: Import-Package: Not able to start Activator

Tags: java, jpa, osgi

I am trying to work on an example where `JPA` is used in `OSGi`, but I am facing a weird issue while starting the activator.

When I start the activator a validation dialog box pops up and says the above error. I have imported the packages and its the first time I am seeing this problem.

[image]

I have the following **Activator** class:

```
package org.aricent.jpaosgi;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
 */
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello World!!");

    try {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("todos");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#stop(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
 */
public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Goodbye World!!");
}
```

}

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
META-persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml
JPA-PersistenceUnits: todos
Bundle-Name: JpaOsgi
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.aricent.jpaOsgi
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: org.aricent.jpaosgi.Activator
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: javax.persistence;version="2.1.0",
                org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="todos" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>myJPAProject.Todo</class>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
    value="jdbc:derby:/home/vogella/databases/simpleDb;create=true" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test" />

  <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
    value="database" />
</properties>
```

Can anyone plz help me out here. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a "weird issue".

You have imported these packages but not provided bundles that export them. All imported packages must be matched by a corresponding export, either from another bundle or from the base framework/runtime (the "system bundle").

Make sure your run configuration includes bundles that export the required packages.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have any compile time errors, your run configuration is the issue here. You need to add the bundles providing the missing packages to the bundles you include at run time.